# Is Git appropriate to manage a csv based database?

Tags: database, git, csv

I have  database in the form of a few csv files. Multiple people will be editing and expanding this database, so I would like a way to keep track of the specific changes that are made. Also, before changes are accepted they need to pass certain integrity tests.

I was thinking about using git (with github), but I heard it is not appropriate for keeping track of csv files. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: csv is text. git is fine with text, in general. maybe you have a special case, though.

Comment: Here are some insights into my own question: http://paulfitz.github.io/2014/07/09/diff-merge-csv.html

Comment: The reason I ask this question is because it seems that git is designs to work with source code, not databases.

Comment: *"I **heard** it is not appropriate for keeping track of csv files."* Where?

Comment: Git doesn't care what the text is, whether csv or code.  Whoever told you that isn't familiar with how it works. And whoever told you csv is a database, doesn't know their stuff. You need better resources. :)

Comment: That is why I came here, for better resources.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs allows for collaborative editing of tables which includes commenting and tracking changes.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets